# Cake php project not working in xampp localhost

Tags: php, cakephp, xampp

I am trying to set up my cake php application from live server to xampp in my local machine but i am getting number of errors when i run it in my local. it is working good in live server. please check below link for issue.

```
   Warning: Uncaught exception 'SocketException' with message 'SMTP Error: 535 5.7.8 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 nt15sm10027203pdb.14 - gsmtp' in E:\xampp\htdocs\football\lib\Cake\Network\Email\SmtpTransport.php:253 Stack trace: #0 E:\xampp\htdocs\football\lib\Cake\Network\Email\SmtpTransport.php(144): SmtpTransport->_smtpSend('U3VwZXJkb2cxMg=...', '235') #1 E:\xampp\htdocs\football\lib\Cake\Network\Email\SmtpTransport.php(60): SmtpTransport->_auth() #2 E:\xampp\htdocs\football\lib\Cake\Network\Email\CakeEmail.php(1121): SmtpTransport->send(Object(CakeEmail)) #3 E:\xampp\htdocs\football\app\Lib\AppError.php(27): CakeEmail->send('
Error<...')
#4 E:\xampp\htdocs\football\app\Model\Article.php(2): AppError::handleError(2, 'require_once(Sh...', 'E:\\xampp\\htdocs...', 2, Array)
#5 E:\xampp\htdocs\football\app\Model\Article.php(2): require_once()
#6 E:\xampp\htdocs\football\lib\Cake\Core\App.php(565): include('E:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#7 [internal function]: App::load('Article')
#8 [interna in E:\xampp\htdocs\football\lib\Cake\Network\Email\SmtpTransport.php on line 253



Fatal error:  main(): Failed opening required 'Share/TwitterAPIExchange.php' (include_path='.;E:\xampp\php\PEAR') in E:\xampp\htdocs\football\app\Model\Article.php on line 2



Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'SocketException' with message 'SMTP Error: 535 5.7.8 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 w17sm10030731pdj.6 - gsmtp' in E:\xampp\htdocs\football\lib\Cake\Network\Email\SmtpTransport.php:253
Stack trace:
#0 E:\xampp\htdocs\football\lib\Cake\Network\Email\SmtpTransport.php(144): SmtpTransport->_smtpSend('U3VwZXJkb2cxMg=...', '235')
#1 E:\xampp\htdocs\football\lib\Cake\Network\Email\SmtpTransport.php(60): SmtpTransport->_auth()
#2 E:\xampp\htdocs\football\lib\Cake\Network\Email\CakeEmail.php(1121): SmtpTransport->send(Object(CakeEmail))
#3 E:\xampp\htdocs\football\app\Lib\AppError.php(27): CakeEmail->send('<pre><h1>Error<...')
#4 [internal function]: AppError::handleError(64, 'main(): Failed ...', 'E:\\xampp\\htdocs...', 2, Array)
#5 E:\xampp\htdocs\football\lib\Cake\Core\App.php(929): call_user_func('AppError::handl...', 64, 'main(): Failed ...', 'E:\\xampp\\htdocs...', 2, Array)
#6 E:\xampp\htdocs\football\lib\Cake\Core\App.php(902): App::_checkFatalError()
#7 [interna in E:\xampp\htdocs\football\lib\Cake\Network\Email\SmtpTransport.php on line 253
```

Comment: What errors you are getting?

Comment: please check i have put error there

Comment: I'd say `Failed opening required 'Share/TwitterAPIExchange.php'` is pretty clear - you are trying to load something and it is not there. As for the SMTP errors, did you read the related Google Mail articles?

Comment: can you please share that article with me

Comment: Check your email configuration at `\app\Config\email.php`.

Answer (score 0):

1: Open your localhost php.ini file. It is located inside your server’s PHP directory.

2: Inside php.ini please add the following code and save your modified php.ini file.

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

3: If still not working then verify your smtpOptions and rights

Comment: extension=php_openssl.dll  this line already present in my php.ini  can you please more descript 3rd point

Comment: I had this problem and when I activated the Google Authenticator Verification I set up the 2-Step-Authentication in gmail.

Visit https://www.google.com/settings/security, click the "App Password" - Settings.

Select "Other", enter any name you like, copy the code and paste it to your projects settings.

I don't know if will solve your problem. Also you could try to go to  https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps to change the "Access for less secure apps" to Enabled.